# How to submit branching Spark tasks in Parallel (not sequential)

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following process in Spark. I create a DataFrame through a process, then I sample the data frame into 2 pieces. I then perform a few more operations on these halves, and then save both. Right now, I run the two save processes sequentially. When the first halve is nearly finished, the next task does not start processing, so I have a down time in my executors. Is there a way I can submit both tasks async so that they operate in parallel, and not sequentially?

```
val split = 0.99
val frac1 = 0.7
val frac2 = (1 - frac1)
val frac3 = split

val validated = sqlContext.sql("Select * from Validated")

val splitDF = validated.selectExpr("srch_id").distinct.cache.randomSplit(Array(
  frac1 * frac3, frac2 * frac3, (1 - frac1 * frac3 - frac2 * frac3)
), 1122334455)   

val traindf = validated.as("val").join(splitDF(0).as("train"), $"val.srch_id" === $"train.srch_id", "inner").selectExpr(sel.toSeq: _*)
val scoredf = validated.as("val").join(splitDF(1).as("score"), $"val.srch_id" === $"score.srch_id", "inner").selectExpr(sel.toSeq: _*)

traindf.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).saveAsTable("train") //Holds until finished saving
scoredf.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).saveAsTable("score")
```

I am considering using threads, but am unsure if DataFrames are threadsafe. It seems that sometimes both tables do not save with the following approach.

```
import scala.concurrent._

val pool = new forkjoin.ForkJoinPool(8)
val ectx = ExecutionContext.fromExecutorService(pool)

sqlContext.sql("use testpx")

ectx.execute(
  new Runnable {
    def run {
      traindf.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).saveAsTable("train")
    }
  }
)
ectx.execute(
  new Runnable {
    def run {
      scoredf.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).saveAsTable("test")
    }
  }
)

ectx.shutdown
ectx.awaitTermination(Long.MaxValue, java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.DAYS)
```